# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my code:

```
window.onload = function () {
var main = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        currentActivity: 'home'
    }
});
Vue.component('home', {
    template: '#home-template'
});
};
```

This is my template:

```
<head>
     <script type="text/x-template" id="home-template">
      <div class="banner dark">
        <div class="content">says some shit</div>
      </div>
      <div class="banner light">
        <div class="content">says some other shit</div>
      </div>
    </script>
</head>
```

When I load the page I get this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: home
```

and this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_refID' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle, everything looks fine in your code ?

Answer (score 7):

You have to either create your `Vue.component` before the creation of the Vue ViewModel, that is before the `new Vue({})`, or create your `Vue.component` inside the ViewModel in `created` event.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5rLaah0/1/) with the first approach and here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5rLaah0/2/) showing the second approach.